# how to extract indices of a vector for missing values in R

Tags: r, indices

I am trying to extract the position indices of missing values of a vector.

I have a vector which is length 46, but I know it should have 72 values. The other values are implicitly missing. For example, j is the vector of the valid indices and i is the vector of all 1-72 indices:

`> j [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  8  9 11 13 15 16 17 20 21 22 23 25 27 31 32 33 35 38 39 40 41 45 46 47 48 50 52 53 57 59 61 62 63 64 65 67 68 69 70 71`

```
    i <- 1:72
```

I have tried `i[!=j]`, but this produces an error - `Error: unexpected '!=' in "i[!="`
but i[j] gives the correct 46 indices.

Please can somebody advise.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Maybe `i[-j]` ?

Comment: `setdiff(i, j)`

Comment: Thanks for your comments and suggestions.